# What is the difference between url and path in Laravel? Can I use path to load JavaScript or CSS?

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel, and I have some custom script for some pages and I put them in `'public/custom/js/test.js'`.

Now I want to use any URL helper functions so that I don't want to write the full path of JavaScript or CSS. Can I use `public_path()` function to load a JavaScript file?

When I print `public_path()`, it comes like `'D:\xampp\htdocs\erp\public'`, but I want the forward slash.

What is the difference between forward slash (`/`) and backward slash (`\`)?

Comment: Just use `url('custom/js/test.js')`. `asset` works too, and IIRC has some optional features around CDNs. Path is for server-side filesystem work - the user's browser can't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to add a script. This one uses the URL helper:

```
<script src="{{ asset('custom/js/test.js') }}"></script>
```

In URL's the 'path separator' is always a forward slash. For file paths it depends on the OS: Windows uses backslashes and most others use the forward slash.